# Passing parameters by class fields, overridden class methods or Properties

Tags: java

I was wondering lately, which one of the three methods of passing parameters to the method - presented below - are the best for you, your CPU, memory and why. I am considering methods which allow me to pass more arguments in future, without changing the method signature.

If you know something better, I am here to listen and learn.

## Pass by methods

#### Params.java

```
public interface Params {
    int getParamOne();
    int getParamTwo();
}
```

#### Calling

```
obj.foo(new Params() {

    @Override
    public int getParamOne() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getParamOne() {
        return 2;
    }
});
```

#### Receiving

```
public void foo(Params p) {
    int p1 = p.getParamOne();
    int p2 = p.getParamTwo();
}
```

---

## Pass by class fields

#### Params.java

```
public class Params {
    private int paramOne;
    private int paramTwo;

    // Getters and setters here
}
```

#### Calling and receiving

No magic here, just create a new Params object, use setters, pass it to the method and use getters.

---

## Pass by Properties class

#### Calling

```
properties.put("paramOne", 1);
properties.put("paramTwo", 2);
obj.foo(properties);
```

#### Receiving

```
public void foo(Properties properties) {
    int a = (int) properties.get("paramOne");
    int b = (int) properties.get("paramTwo");
}
```

---

I was pleased to show an real-life example of code, which actually needs passing varying types and number of properties. I'm using the third method - passing by the properties:

```
public interface DataProvider {
    public String getContent(Properties properties);
}

public class HttpProvider implements DataProvider {
    @Override
    public String getContent(Properties properties) {
        InputStream in = new URL(properties.get("URL")).openStream();
        String content = IOUtils.toString(in);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        return content;
    }

public class FtpProvider implements DataProvider {
    @Override
    public String getContent(Properties properties) {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(properties.get("server"), properties.get("port"));
        ftpClient.login(properties.get("user"), properties.get("pass"));
        // Get file stream and save the content to a variable here
        return content;
    }
}
```

One interface for a different methods of obtaining a file. I am not persisting that this is good or not, it's just an example of code I've stumbled upon in my current project in work and I was wondering if could it be done better.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. In many cases all of these ideas are bad.

Comment: @Kayaman why bad? Sometimes you don't want to or just can't pass everything in a method parameters.

Comment: Of course not. You might want to pass for example a `Map` when it's necessary. However I believe that you think it's necessary more often than it really is. Your idea of passing more arguments without modifying the method signature is not very sound. You'll have to modify the method anyway if you want the extra parameter to do anything. Not to mention you'll lose the Strong typing, so you have no idea if you're passing the correct type and amount of parameters. If you have a specific case where you think your ideas are necessary, edit your post to show that. There's probably a good solution.

Comment: @Kayaman i have edited my question and added an example code from my current project. Check it out and let me know what you think.

Comment: A better solution would be to have the providers take the required parameters in their constructor. Then your `getContent()` doesn't even need any parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of a "Params" class is better than properties, in performance. The java compiler can handle such short lived classes quite well.

- One sees properties on some constructors / factory methods, like for XML and such.
- One sees a parameter containing class in larger systems, to keep the API restricted to one parameter, and not use overloaded methods.

I would do:

```
public class Params {
    public final int a;
    public final int b;

    public Params(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

And in the class immediately use `params.a`.

For the rest there is also the *Builder Pattern*, but that would be more a substitute for a complex constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Signatures in interfaces should not ever change!!! If you contemplate to change APIs in the future (i.e. change, add or remove a parameter), an acceptable way may be by incapsulating your parameters in objects in order to do not break signatures.

Comment: Yes, I know, I've pointed it out: "I am considering methods which allow me to pass more arguments in future, **without** changing the method signature.".

Comment: Look that parameters (or how many parameters you have) are part of your method signature, be careful ;-)

Comment: @itachi What you're considering is bad design. However if you really think that you you've come up with a smart idea here, just have every method take in `Map<Object, Object>`. You'll be able to pass in pretty much anything you want, and eventually you'll realize why it was a bad idea to begin with. You have been warned.